# Laplace operator(inverse delta) in R

Tags: r, ode, pde

I am trying to solve a list of PDEs which consists of a laplace operator. Problem is i don't know how to represent the laplace operator in R.
Example :

```
dX/dt - del(u.X) = 0
```

In this eaquation `del` represents the laplace operator but i don't know how to write it in R.
This is the Wikipedia link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Diffusion) that have a mathematical description about this operator. I am trying model diffussion of a chemical so, i am using this operator in my ODE model. Now the problem is i don't know how to code this operator in R. I am using `deSolve` R package to do this

Comment: Can you write the del operator in standard math notation? The other thing you need is to provide a sample of your input data so we know how the vector components are organized (e.g. a matrix with columns of x,y,z values perhaps).

Comment: It sounds like you want code to perform the operation rather than a means to annotate output. See chapter 9 of "Solving Differential Equations in R".

Comment: This is the Wikipedia link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Diffusion) that have a mathematical description about this operator. I am trying model diffussion of a chemical so, i am using this operator in my ODE model. Now the problem is i don't know how to code this operator in R